# Ember date belongTo with serialized id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, ember-rails

```
App.Locale = DS.Model.extend
  language: DS.belongsTo("language")

App.LocaleSerializer = App.ApplicationSerializer.extend
   attrs:
     language:  { serialize: "id", deserialize: "records" }
```

Using ember with rails as the backend. I am trying to create a locale, which has a dropdown to select a language. My idea is to pass a language_id to the backend, however I get the following when I submit.

```
{"locale"=>{"language"=>"15" }
```

How do I convert this to look like

```
{"locale"=>{"language_id"=>"15" }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the `ActiveModelSerializer`, I think your answer is [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.ActiveModelSerializer.html#property_attrs). Just add the `key` attribute to the hash:

```
App.LocaleSerializer = App.ApplicationSerializer.extend
  attrs:
    language:  { key: "language_id", serialize: "id", deserialize: "records" }
```

If you only want to use `language_id` when serializing, but get `language` when deserializing, you can always override [serializeBelongsTo](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.ActiveModelSerializer.html#method_serializeBelongsTo):

```
App.LocaleSerializer = App.ApplicationSerializer.extend
  serializeBelongsTo: (record, json, relationship) ->
    if relationship.key is 'language'
      json.language_id = Ember.get record, 'language.id'
    else
      @_super record, json, relationship
```